# How do I connect my local python script on my raspberry pi, to a external WAMP server on my desktop?

Tags: php, python, mysql, linux

So I have a sensor set up on my Raspberry Pi that gives a signal indicating whether or not something is in front of it. I have a python script that is used to read the output of sensor. I would like to send this signal to a MySQL database on my WAMP server that is currently located on my desktop. I am currently using the mysql.connector module for the connection. Setting aside the sensor signal and looking at the just the communication of the two entities, I am getting what seems to be a common error.

This is my connector code

```
import mysql.connector



cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',
                              password='***',
                              host='***.***.***.***',
                              database='****')

cnx.close()
```

At this point I just need to get the connection established so this is all I have written so far. After I run the code, I get this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connector.py", line 8, in 
    database='crud')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/**init**.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 719, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 210, in _open_connection
    self._ssl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 144, in _do_auth
    self._auth_switch_request(username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 177, in _auth_switch_request
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'**.**.***.***' (using password: YES)

1.Yes I have the correct address,username, and password. 
2.I have given the correct privileges to the root account.
3.I do have port forwarding, which forwards my raspberry pi address to the correct port on the WAMP server. 
4.I have looked at the Listen statement and it seems to be correct 
5.There is no bind address or skip-networking in my config files.

I am all out of options that I can think of. Kind of new to the programming thing so any advice will help.

Comment: Have you enabled connections for the root user (you probably shouldn't be using the root MySQL user, but that's not super relevant here) to MySQL from eternal boxes (to the local IP address, not 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: At this point Im not worried about security as much as I am the connection. By enabling the connection you mean??

Comment: E.g. by granting access to `'root'@'<ip-address>'` or `'root'@'%'`. You'd also have to make sure that MySQL is listening for connections on your public IP, e.g. by chaniging `bind-address` in `my.cnf` to your public IP or to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: There is currently no bind-address command in the cnf file. I added my public IP with that command and still no luck. I then proceeded to use 0.0.0.0 and it still didnt work.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the machine it's running on via the outward-facing IP address?

Comment: Ok, I found out what my problem was. I was trying to use the same root host from 2 different machines. I created a new user and its working fine now. thank you though!